# C# Convert string to literal Control

Tags: c#, string, literals

I have a literal control named "ltlTextBox1" and "ltlTextBox2"

I would like to do something like this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
   string textbox = "ltlTextBox" + i;
   textbox.Text = "Write this";
}
```

Comment: winform, wpf, asp.net, mvc, ...?? come on, give it a correct tag!

Answer (score 2):

```
TextBox textbox = this.FindControl("ltlTextBox" + i) as TextBox;

if (textbox != null) {
    textbox.Text = "Write this";
}
```

Comment: Woops.  Thanks for the edit Jamiec.

Comment: No worries. I was slightly afraid that its a bit offensive to correct someone else's code.

Comment: people do it all the time here ive had mine edited several times usually just formatting tho

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a [LiteralControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) control in asp.net . This would most likely provide the functionality you need.

Other than that I think we might need more information to help you out as to what/how/where you are trying to use these literal controls.

(Expanding on this)

```
LiteralControl l = this.FindControl("ltlTextBox") as LiteralControl;
l.Text = "My Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code textbox is a variable of type string. String does not have a property called Text.

assigning a value to a variable doesn't change the name of the value. Ie `("ltlTextBox" + 1).ToString()` prints  "ltlTextBox1" whereas  `ltlTextBox1.ToString()` prints System.Web.Ui.Controls.LiterlaControl or what ever the type of that variable is.

You either need to do:

ltlTextBox1.Text = "write this";
 ltlTextBox2.Text = "Write this";

or

```
var controls = new[]{ ltlTextBox1, ltlTextBox2};
  for(int i = 0;i<controls.Length;i++){
    controls[0].Text = "Write this";
  }
```